# Unicode in Bourne Shell source code

Tags: shell, unicode, sh

Is it safe to use UTF-8, and not just the 7-bit ASCII subset, in modern Bourne Shell interpreters, be it in comments (e.g., using box-drawing characters), or by passing arguments to a function or program? I'm considering whether filesystems can safely handle Unicode in path names outside of the scope of this question.

I know at least to not put a BOM in my shell scripts… ever, as that would break the kernel's shebang line parsing.

Comment: Technically, there is no modern Bourne shell. `sh` is the POSIX shell, which is heavily based on `ksh`, which in turn was influenced by, but greatly extends, the Bourne shell.

Comment: Yes, I should have said *POSIX* shell. Good point. As it is already answered, too late to change, given the differences between the two.

Comment: It's a minor point; the given answers are still applicable.

Comment: `ksh` was not influenced by the `Bourne Shell`, but is a software based on the original `Bourne Shell` sources. Given that a modern Bourne Shell exists as well, we currently have two development lines based on the original Bourne Shell sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing about UTF-8 is that any old code that's just passing string data along and uses the C string convention of terminating strings with a null byte works fine. That generally characterizes how the shell handles command names and arguments.

Even if the shell does some string processing with special meanings for ascii characters, UTF-8 still mostly works fine because ascii characters encode exactly the same in UTF-8. So for example the shell will still be able to recognize all its keywords and syntax characters like `[]{}()<>/.?;'"$&*` etc. That characterizes how string literals and other syntax bits of a script should be handled, for example.

You should be able to use UTF-8 in comments, string literals, command names, and command arguments. (of course the system will have to support UTF-8 file names to have UTF-8 commands, and the commands will have to handle UTF-8 command line arguments.)

You may not be able to use UTF-8 in function names or variables, since the shell may be looking for strings of ascii characters there. Although if your locale is UTF-8 then an interpreter that's using the locale based character classification functions internally might work with UTF-8 identifiers as well, but it's probably not portable.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what you are trying to do... In general plain vanilla Bourne-derived shells cannot handle Unicode characters *inside* the scripts, which means your script text must be purely 8-bit ASCII(+) if you care for portability. At the same time pipes are completely encoding neutral, so you can have things like `a | b` where `a` outputs UTF-8 and `b` receives it. So, assuming `find` is capable of handling UTF-8 paths and your processing tool for them can work with UTF-8 strings, you should be OK.

Comment: To add to this, the only problem with using UTF-8 in shell that I am aware of is in identifiers (`foö=5` does not work in `bash`, at least).

Comment: Identifiers I wasn't too worried about identifiers (especially as an anglophone), and I knew about pipes being raw data streams, but I was worried for example, for comments.

Comment: If you were able to name a file Bj\xF4rn previously -- and if you haven't, many of us have, for decades -- then renaming it to Bj\xC3\xB4rn isn't stretching things much farther.

Comment: `dash` does not support multi-byte characters, but the Bourne Shell did get multi-byte support in 1989 for SVr4.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-Byte support was added in 1989 to the Bourne Shell and given that UNICODE was introduced in 1992, you cannot expect UTF-8 from a shell that is older than UNICODE. SunOS introduced UNICODE support when it has become available.

So any Bourne Shell that was derived from the SVr4 Bourne Shell and compiled and linked to a modern library environment should support UTF-8 in scripts.

If you like to verify that, you may get a portable version from the OpenSolaris Bourne Shell in the schily-tools: http://sourceforge.net/projects/schilytools/files/

`osh` is the original Bourne Shell made portable only.

`sh` is the Bourne Shell with modern enhancements.